NLOG - Redirect single webapi controller method logs to specific file
I have a .NET Core 5 Web API that utilizes NLog, currently capturing all the logs in a single file, which is archived daily.
I aim to redirect only the logs generated by a specific controller method to a dedicated file. Is this possible?
I've conducted some tests, but the configuration I've attempted doesn't seem to work:
{
  "logger": "XXX.WebAppApiTest.Controllers.MyController.MyMethod",
  "minLevel": "Info",
  "writeTo": "singleMethodLogFile"
}

other section:
"singleMethodLogFile": {
  "type": "File",
  "fileName": "${aspnet-appbasepath}/Logs/MyMethod_${shortdate}.log",
  "archiveFileName": "${aspnet-appbasepath}/Logs/Archive/MyMethod_${shortdate}.log",
  "maxArchiveFiles": "1",
  "archiveEvery": "Day"
}

Would anyone be able to provide guidance on how to achieve this? Thank you.
Thanks to support

Could you please share your nlog settings? You mean your config set in appsetting.json not working or it log to the file but it doesn't log for specific method?

NLOG is working but what I want is to redirect the logs coming from a specific controlle rmethod to another files. With the configuration above it logs nothing

Could you please share all the nlog settings and configure to let me test with you codes? Currently it looks correct.

"logger": "XXX.WebAppApiTest.Controllers.MyController.MyMethod", will only work if creating a Logger-object with that category-name. Maybe add ILoggerFactory-parameter to the controller-constructor, and explicit create a logger by calling methodLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("XXX.WebAppApiTest.Controllers.MyController.MyMethod") then use methodLogger inside the controller-method.

this is very usefull,  you can post it as answer

Maybe create the _methodLogger for the controller like this:
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ILogger _methodLogger;

    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       _logger = logger;
       _methodLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger($"{GetType()}.{nameof(MyMethod)}");
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
       _methodLogger.LogInfo("Hello from method");
    }
}

Then you can explicit redirect the output from the _methodLogger like this:
{
  "logger": "MyNameSpace.MyController.MyMethod",
  "minLevel": "Info",
  "writeTo": "singleMethodLogFile"
}

